# Click Listener exercised on initilazion but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning javaScript/jQuery and all I want to do is use a loop to put a few pictures on the screen and set a counter that increases each time, the picture is clicked.
From other stackoverflow questions, I learned that for dynamically added DOM-Elements I cannot use jQuery's .click() but should rather use .on('Click','selector','function'). But that doesn't fix it.

For me the code WITHIN the listner is excercised once (I.e. the counter for each dogs is set to 1) and then a click on a picture yields:

```
jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Here is my code:

I am particularly interested in/referring to this part:

```
// add a click counter to the click-per-dog-array
        // initialize array element
        clicksPerDog[i] = 0;
        idString = "#"+wugel;
        // create listener
        $('#dogsWrapper').on('click',idString,function(j,fidString){

            console.log("the j passed to the function is: "+j.toString());
            //increase click counter
            clicksPerDog[j]++;
            // update text
            $(fidString).text('This dog has been clicked: '+clicksPerDog[j].toString()+" times.");
        }(i,idString));
```

For those interested, here is the whole shebang:

```
/*
*
* Click counter practice
*
*/

// HTML bits and variables to reuse for each dog
var HTMLDogContainer= "<div id='%dogname%' class='dogcontainer'></div>";

var HTMLDogName = "<h1 >%dogname%</h1>";
var HTMLDogImage = '<img src="resources/%dogname%.jpg" alt="%dogname%" class="dogpic">';
var HTMLCounterText ='<div class="counterText" id="%idtext%"> This dog has not been clicked yet. Counter is %numberClick%.</div>';
var HTMLDogButton ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">%dogname%</button>';

var dogNames = ["Bonzo","Fox","Jimbo","Larry","Mike"];
console.log("dogNames length is this: "+dogNames.length.toString());
var clicksPerDog = [];

var tmpDogContainer, tmpDogName, tmpDogImage, tmpCounterText, tmpDogButton, tmpIdString;

// Let's loop over the dogs in our array and create the elements
for (var i = 0; i < dogNames.length; i++) {  // The number, when thinking 1-indexed, we're on is simply i+1
    // Create a div containing the whole shebang for each dogs
    tmpDogContainer = HTMLDogContainer.replace('%dogname%', dogNames[i]);
    tmpIdString = '#' + dogNames[i]; // Make it identifiable in this loop for jQuery ID Selector purposes
    console.log('tmpIdString: ' + tmpIdString);
    $('#dogsWrapper').append(tmpDogContainer); // append it to the DOM

    // create content for the dog and append it to its respective wrapper
    tmpDogName = HTMLDogName.replace('%dogname%', dogNames[i]); // header with dogname
    $(tmpIdString).append(tmpDogName);

    tmpDogImage = HTMLDogImage.replace('%dogname%', dogNames[i]); //image
    $(tmpIdString).append(tmpDogImage);

    tmpCounterText = HTMLCounterText.replace('%numberClick%', '0'); //counter
    var wugel = dogNames[i].toString() + "counter";
    tmpCounterText = tmpCounterText.replace('%idtext%', wugel); //counter
    $(tmpIdString).append(tmpCounterText);

    // create a button for the dog
    tmpDogButton = HTMLDogButton.replace('%dogname%', dogNames[i]);
    $('#dogSelector').append(tmpDogButton); // append it to the DOM

    // add a click counter to the click-per-dog-array
    // initialize array element
    clicksPerDog[i] = 0;
    idString = "#"+wugel;
    // create listener
    $('#dogsWrapper').on('click',idString,function(j,fidString){

        console.log("the j passed to the function is: "+j.toString());
        //increase click counter
        clicksPerDog[j]++;
        // update text
        $(fidString).text('This dog has been clicked: '+clicksPerDog[j].toString()+" times.");
    }(i,idString));

  }
```

For this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Doggo</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- My own CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="dogsWrapper">

    </div>
    <div class="dog-selection-area">
      <p>Select the dog you would like to click:</p>
      <div id="dogSelector" class="btn-group">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/skript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is the value of `idString`?

Comment: Also try changing `$('#dogsWrapper').on('click',idString,function(j,fidString){` to `$(document).on('click',idString,function(j,fidString){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this sample implementation.
Clicking on "This dog has not been clicked yet.", increases the click count.
Treat it as a direction to proceed further with your changes.

Few things to note:

1. You hadn't wrapped your code in $(document).ready.
2. Since you need a counter for each dog, you may need an object for which dog name will be the key and the click count as the value.
3. I have corrected the code for this sample.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


        // HTML bits and variables to reuse for each dog
        var HTMLDogContainer = "<div id='%dogname%' class='dogcontainer'></div>";

        var HTMLDogName = "<h1 >%dogname%</h1>";
        var HTMLDogImage = '<img src="resources/%dogname%.jpg" alt="%dogname%" class="dogpic">';
        var HTMLCounterText = '<div class="counterText" id="%idtext%"> This dog has not been clicked yet. Counter is %numberClick%.</div>';
        var HTMLDogButton = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">%dogname%</button>';

        var dogNames = ["Bonzo", "Fox", "Jimbo", "Larry", "Mike"];
        //console.log("dogNames length is this: " + dogNames.length.toString());
        //var clicksPerDog = [];

        var tmpDogContainer, tmpDogName, tmpDogImage, tmpCounterText, tmpDogButton, tmpIdString;

        // Let's loop over the dogs in our array and create the elements
        for (var i = 0; i < dogNames.length; i++) {  // The number, when thinking 1-indexed, we're on is simply i+1
            // Create a div containing the whole shebang for each dogs
            tmpDogContainer = HTMLDogContainer.replace('%dogname%', dogNames[i]);
            tmpIdString = '#' + dogNames[i]; // Make it identifiable in this loop for jQuery ID Selector purposes
            //console.log('tmpIdString: ' + tmpIdString);
            $('#dogsWrapper').append(tmpDogContainer); // append it to the DOM

            // create content for the dog and append it to its respective wrapper
            tmpDogName = HTMLDogName.replace('%dogname%', dogNames[i]); // header with dogname
            $(tmpIdString).append(tmpDogName);

            tmpDogImage = HTMLDogImage.replace('%dogname%', dogNames[i]); //image
            $(tmpIdString).append(tmpDogImage);

            tmpCounterText = HTMLCounterText.replace('%numberClick%', '0'); //counter
            var wugel = dogNames[i].toString() + "counter";
            tmpCounterText = tmpCounterText.replace('%idtext%', wugel); //counter
            $(tmpIdString).append(tmpCounterText);

            // create a button for the dog
            tmpDogButton = HTMLDogButton.replace('%dogname%', dogNames[i]);
            $('#dogSelector').append(tmpDogButton); // append it to the DOM

            // add a click counter to the click-per-dog-array
            // initialize array element
            
            //idString = "#" + wugel;
            // create listener
        }
        clicksPerDog = {
            Bonzocounter: 0,
            Foxcounter: 0,
            Jimbocounter: 0,
            Larrycounter: 0,
            Mikecounter: 0

        };
        $('#dogsWrapper').on('click', function (e) {

            var id = e.target.id;
            if (id.indexOf('counter') >=0) {
                clicksPerDog[id]++;
                // update text
                $('#' + id).text('This dog has been clicked: ' + clicksPerDog[id] + " times.");
            }
            
        });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="dogsWrapper">
        
    </div>
    <div class="dog-selection-area">
      <p>Select the dog you would like to click:</p>
      <div id="dogSelector" class="btn-group">
          Dog
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pankaj! I am really glad you took the time to answer this thoroughly. Best regards!

Comment: Glad to help you!